# Selenium JAVA crashing chrome as soon as its launched

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automation-testing

`Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 18032
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.

(chrome not reachable)

```
 (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 

Host info: host: 'RDS-EX-HOST1', ip: '192.168.1.203'
```

Build info: version: '4.9.1', revision: 'eb2032df7f'

System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.6'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], extensions: []}}]}]

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:94)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:165)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:183)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:52)
at Intro.main(Intro.java:19)`
```

Chrome driver version - 114.0.5735.90
Chrome version - 114.0.5735.199

running on virtual machine

CODE:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
        co.addArguments("--headless");
        co.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        co.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://google.com");

    }
```

Comment: Is `C:\\Users\\Downloads\\...` correct? I would expect `C:\\Users\\SOMEUSERNAME\\Downloads\\...`